# Is there any way to style one class multiple ways?

Tags: html, css

For example if I want many squares but want them to be different colours is it possible for them to be all the same class? Such as,

```
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
```

or is the only possible way for them to have their own colours is to give them each their own class? Such as

```
  <div class="squares-1"></div>
  <div class="squares-2"></div>
  <div class="squares-3"></div>
```

etc...

I'm wondering because I've been doing it the second way, but it seems like there has to be some other way to do this, the amount of extra CSS almost seems like to much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use multiple classes:

```
<div class="squares square-1"></div>
<div class="squares square-2"></div>
<div class="squares square-3"></div>
```

And then in CSS:

```
.squares { width: 100px; height: 100px; };
.square-1 { background: red; }
.square-2 { background: yellow; }
.square-3 { background: blue; }
```

In css you can also match multiple classes:

```
<div class="square odd">1</div>
<div class="square even">2</div>
<div class="square odd">3</div>
<div class="square even">4</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square.odd { background: red; }
.square.even { background: blue; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the :nth-child selector

```
.squares {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: red;
}

.squares:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}

.squares:nth-child(3) {
    background: blue;
}

.squares:nth-child(4) {
    background: pink;
}

.squares:nth-child(5) {
    background: black;
}

.squares:nth-child(6) {
    background: purple;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3ztmyvu7/

Though personally, I would avoid doing this and giving descriptive classes to your elements, like:

```
.squares.blue {
    background: blue
}

.squares.purple {
    background: purple
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `square` class and add `style="color:whatever"`, as the most nested answer overides the others for itself.

Comment: Even though that would save you from writing a little bit of extra code, it's still not good practice to use nested CSS.

Comment: @Teldridge11 I meant in the div like Pyrxes answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct, but you could also just use `id=color` as well:

```
<div class="squares" id=square1></div>
<div class="squares" id=square2></div>
<div class="squares" id=square3></div>
<div class="squares" id=square4></div>
<div class="squares" id=square5></div>
<div class="squares" id=square6></div>
```

Then give `class=squares` all the attributes you'd like every square to have:

```
.squares {
    # Attributes for ALL squares
}
```

Each different square also can have it's own attributes in addition to the general `squares` attributes:

```
#square1 {
    color: blue;
} 
#square2 {
    color: red;
} 
#square3 {
    color: green;
} 
#square4 {
    color: orange;
} 
#square5 {
    color:purple;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="squares" style="background-color: black"></div>
<div class="squares" style="position: absolute"></div>
```

In short, yes.